# pointers *char and &char

Tags: c++, pointers

I have doubt on below programme

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    char *chr = "hello";
    cout<<chr; //hello
     cout<<endl;

     cout<<*chr; //h
     cout<<endl;

    cout<<*(&chr); //hello
system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

why second cout prints h where as third one prints hello when represents the same

Comment: In the third case you are dereferencing a pointer to a pointer, hence you pass a pointer to cout. The statement (&chr) gives you a temporary pointer to the variable chr. Hence *(&chr) dereferences the pointer (&chr). But chr is a pointer, so you are left with a pointer.

Comment: `char *chr = "hello";` should at least yield a warning. Dare I ask how old is the compiler you're using?

Comment: @Potatoswatter `_tmain` hints at MSVC. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx) reads : "This is allowed in C code, but is deprecated in C++98 and removed in C++11".

Answer (score 5):

To be a little bit more explicit. `chr` is a pointer pointing to a chunk of memory where the characters 'h','e','l','l' and 'o' are stored. After the last character of `chr` is a terminating `\0`. This is needed to signal that the chunk pointed by `chr` is now over.

When passing `chr` to cout, cout will read (not cout it self but the underlying function wich is called by using the `<<` operator) this chunk up to the terminating `\0`. When passing `*chr` to `cout` you dereference the pointer and simply pass the first character pointed by `chr` to `cout` ('h').

`*(&chr)` is the same thing as just `chr` because the adress-of operator gives you the adress of `chr` wich is a pointer to a pointer to character. Dereferencing it using `*` will then give you the pointer pointing to the chunk of memory starting with 'h' and `cout`will again read up to the terminating `\0`.

**EDIT**

As birdypme pointed out correctly, the `*` operator (dereferencing operator) is the inverse to the address-of operator. It is like `+` and `-`. Therefore something like this

```
cout << *(&(*(&chr))) << endl;
```

will still be the same as

```
cout << chr << endl;
```

You can do this to infinity if you like to.

```
cout << *(&(*(&(*(&(*(&(*(&(*(&(*(&chr))))))))))))) << endl; // I hope i didn't miss a ')'
```

Comment: I would even add that the '*' operator is the inverse of the '&' operator, so that *(&(*(&(*(&pointer))))) is still the same as pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second case, you are passing to cout a single `char`, the one pointed by `chr`, that is the first of the C-string `"hello"`.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you are *dereferencing* the pointer. This is the same as using `chr[0]` and in this case it is `h`.

In the last example you are taking the address of `chr` and then dereferencing:

`&chr --> char**`

`*(&chr) --> char*`

So at the and you again have a `char*`

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

```
cout<<*chr; is same as cout<<chr[0];
```

because the pointer is dereferenced and passes only the first character pointed by `chr`

In case of `cout<<*(&chr);` , if i convert it into words, it would be, print the value present at the address of `chr`. Now since `chr`is a pointer, you will get a pointer to a pointer by this statement `&chr`and the again you are dereferencing it, which gives you `hello`.